# how do I pass the name of a dictionary as an argument to my function

Tags: python, dictionary

```
data = {'employer':'Apppe, Inc', 'title': 'Senior Software Engineer', 'manager': 'Steve Jobs', 'city': 'Cupertino'}


def my_function(**data):
    employername  = data['employer']
    title = data['title']
    manager = data['manager']
    city = data['city']
    print(city)
    
    
my_function(**data)
username = input("Enter dictionary name:")
my_function(**username)
```

If I enter the text data into the input. I get this strange error.

```
Enter dictionary name:data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
TypeError: __main__.my_function() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str

[Program finished]
```

Comment: That sounds like an XY problem. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Agree with Selcuk. This is seriously weird stuff, and unless you are *really* sure what you are doing — and, to be blunt, the fact that do do not understand the error message indicates that you aren’t — you should probably consider 1) just passing a dictionary, not using the `**` key-value-hack, and 2) making the dictionaries you with the user to select between the values of another dictionary, and the user input the key to that dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `locals()` function to get a dictionary of all local variables, then get the local variable specified by the user. Just like this:

```
data = {'employer':'Apppe, Inc', 'title': 'Senior Software Engineer', 'manager': 'Steve Jobs', 'city': 'Cupertino'}


def my_function(**data):
    employername  = data['employer']
    title = data['title']
    manager = data['manager']
    city = data['city']
    print(city)
    
    
my_function(**data)
username = input("Enter dictionary name:")
my_function(**(locals()[username]))
```

Note: use this function carefully and **always** sanitize user input! If you don't, then you can open yourself up to an injection attack.